# What's the benefit of including .d.ts (declaration file of typescript) in release package?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I took a look inside `node_modules` folder for `ionic-angular` package.
Inside each component also includes `.d.ts` for example `menu-controller.js` file, there would also be `menu-controller.d.ts`.

Please note what we need is just javascript file to use in the project.
So in this case what's the benefit of including such `.d.ts` file with the release package?

The following is content in `menu-controller.d.ts` file.

```
import { Menu } from './menu';
import { MenuType } from './menu-types';
import { Platform } from '../../platform/platform';
export declare class MenuController {
    private _menus;
    open(menuId?: string): Promise<boolean>;
    close(menuId?: string): Promise<boolean>;
    toggle(menuId?: string): Promise<boolean>;
    enable(shouldEnable: boolean, menuId?: string): Menu;
    swipeEnable(shouldEnable: boolean, menuId?: string): Menu;
    isOpen(menuId?: string): boolean;
    isEnabled(menuId?: string): boolean;
    get(menuId?: string): Menu;
    getOpen(): Menu;
    getMenus(): Array<Menu>;
    register(menu: Menu): void;
    unregister(menu: Menu): void;
    static registerType(name: string, cls: new (...args: any[]) => MenuType): void;
    static create(type: string, menuCmp: Menu, platform: Platform): MenuType;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because some other people might be using that package in a Typescript project, and having the .d.ts files with the package means that they don't need to install it from another place such as definitely typed

Comment: Does it mean that it's not sufficient to have only javascript files in typescript project? Im pretty new to the space. I think as in final we transpire .ts to .js, I would like to know which particular step we still do need such declaration (in .ts) in typescript project.

Comment: In theory it is enough just having the .js file, but in practice, using typescript and not having the .d.ts files means that the typescript compiler won't know what functions or properties are available to use, so basically you would get not type benefits

Comment: im almost there, thanks. Just one last thing, im curious that in the case of release package, there's no .ts files included then how would typescript project gain such benefit from types information.

Comment: if a package contains no .d.ts you can still check projects like "definitely typed" where it contains a huge source of typings submitted by the community, you can pull them from there to gain such benefits. or you can use tools such as "typings" that will do that for you